# Degrees of freedom in an photon counting experiment for chi squared test

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, degrees-of-freedom

I am attempting to apply a chi-squared test to determine the goodness of fit between modeled and experimental data of a photon counting experiment. My data sets are two histograms, each with 75 bins. The histograms represent the number of photons detected at different energy level. More clearly stated, each bin is an energy level and the height represents the photons detected at that energy level.

My question: how many degrees of freedom are in this comparison? Is it the number of energy levels minus one (the number of bins minus one)?

Thank you all so much for your time and help!

Comment: Welcome to Cross-Validated! To clarify - by "goodness of fit" do you want to test if the modelled and experimental count of photons at each energy level are from the same distribution?

Comment: Hi @Lynn, Yes, essentially, I want to show that the simulation is an accurate model of the experiment.